Django Allauth 65.2.0 headless mode - session token problems
I have a setup with django, drf, django-allauth headless and nextjs acting somewhat as a proxy to my django api, completely decoupled and server from different servers (a regular django setup and separate node server for next)
Settings:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]
HEADLESS_ONLY = True
HEADLESS_FRONTEND_URLS = {}
# HEADLESS_TOKEN_STRATEGY = "apps.core.backends.allauth_token_strategy.DRFTokenAndAnonSessionTokenStrategy"

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "APP": {
            "client_id": config.OAUTH.GOOGLE.CLIENT_ID,
            "secret": config.OAUTH.GOOGLE.CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
        "SCOPE": [
            "profile",
            "email",
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {
            "access_type": "offline",
        },
        "OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED": True,
    }
}

URLs: (the change is purely for aesthetics)
from allauth.headless.constants import Client
from allauth.headless.urls import build_urlpatterns
from django.urls import path, include
from django.urls.resolvers import RoutePattern


def build_allauth_url_patterns():
    path_object = build_urlpatterns(Client.APP)[0]
    path_object.pattern = RoutePattern("")
    return [path_object]


urlpatterns = [
    path("user/", include((build_allauth_url_patterns(), "headless"), namespace="app")),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
]

I want to use the headless mode since I don't need the CSRF features of django allauth browser implementation, however I want to use the handshake of django-allauth so I'm sending a post request to the api via a form from nextjs.
for this example consider my domain as localhost
<form method="post" action="https://api.localhost/v1/user/auth/provider/redirect" className="w-full">
  <Button variant="outline" className="gap-2 w-full" type="submit">
    <Icons.LogIn />
    <span>Sign Up With Google</span>
  </Button>
  <Input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="https://auth.localhost/accounts/google/login/callback/" />
  <Input type="hidden" name="process" value="login" />
  <Input type="hidden" name="provider" value="google" />
</form>

With this, the form successfully redirects to google for authorizing my app, and I can authorize with the scope from my settings and continue to my app. But at this point, django allauth returns an error response - from why understand - because I don't have a session identifier/key.
In allauth.socialaccout.providers.oauth2.views.OAuth2CallbackView.dispatch the call to allauth.socialaccout.providers.oauth2.views.OAuth2CallbackView._get_state returns this error response because in _get_sate the state is always None. This is how far I was able to track it, I tried to figure out how to get a session_token to put it to X-Session-Token header but since handshake is a redirect from google to my app I can't change the header, since I'm using the APP version and not BROWSER version I don't have a cookie (In a non browser app you wouldn't have this anyway, and the provider_token endpoint still requires it as per the docs)
Now my question is, if I'm right and I need the session somehow how can I have the session identified by django so state = statekit.unstash_state(request, state_id) actually returns the correct state? Or if I'm wrong and there is something else that's wrong, what is that?
Update 1:
I dug deeper and confirmed the problem is about sessions, the request coming from google doesn't have the session information even though when we initiate the provider redirect the session is created. I'm not sure why but it seems like there is no sessionid cookie even though the session is created.
Update 2:
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = self.handle(request, *args, **kwargs)
    breakpoint()
    return self.handle(request, *args, **kwargs)

If I put a breakpoint in allauth.headless.internal.restkit.views.RestView.dispatch like this, the request.session.modified is True and the session data added via statekit.stash_state is there. However when I put a breakpoint to my LAST middleware to inspect the request/response, somehow the session data is not there anymore. With that, it is missing from the latter middlewares, and most importantly it is missing in the session middleware which - since it is missing - doesn't set the sessionid cookie.
I've created a quick django view as a sanity check
def hello(request):
    request.session["foo"] = "bar"
    from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World!")

Which actually successfully adds the sessionid since this modifies the session. So I think it is not some other configuration of mine but solely on allauth's configurations.
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "apps.common.utils.media_whitenoise_middleware.MediaWhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware",
    "pghistory.middleware.HistoryMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

Here are my middleware, like I said, the above sanity check function works so I don't think the issue is with any middleware here and like I said, by the time it comes to XFrameOptionsMiddleware.get_response the request.session already somehow loses its data.
Update 3:
Seems like allauth.headless.internal.authkit.authentication_context is to blame, it replaces the session with a new one - I'm not sure why but it seems like by the time finally runs and restores the previous session, if I simply skip this function I see the session_id and rest of the authentication flow somewhat works as expected.
Update 4:
Well, I clearly haven't thought this through as I am just realizing that I have no way of retrieving the session without reading back the cookie in which case I can just use the cookies for the rest of the flow soooooo nevermind this whole quetstion. Leaving this here undeleted since the issue in allauth repo references this.
